# How to get the view of an action item?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-view

What i want to do is get the view of my action bar item, so i can display my QuickActionDialog on the exact place. I tried this, but my quick action dialog appear on the top left corner of the screen above the action bar (and above my item/button).

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(createCustomItemView(R.drawable.ic_add));         
questionPup.show(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getCustomView());


public View createCustomItemView(int resId) {
    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    ImageView iconView = new ImageView(getSherlockActivity());
    iconView.setImageDrawable(icon);
    return iconView;
}
```

What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference of iconView in your activity;

```
    ImageView iconView = null;

    public View createCustomItemView(int resId) {
        if (this.iconView == null) {
            Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
            this.iconView= new ImageView(getSherlockActivity());
            this.iconView.setImageDrawable(icon);
        }
        return this.iconView;
    }
```

Then you shoudl be able to call :

```
mActionBarQuickAction.show(iconView);
```

whenever you want and the iconView will act as the anchor point (mActionBarQuickAction is your reference to your quickaction you created earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but my dialog still remains in the top-left corner :(